# Bot Framework: Tagging messages

Tags: json, tags, bots, botframework

So, when a bot sends a message through Bot Connecter, it sends it as a JSON object, that lookks something like:

```
{
  "type": "message",
  "timestamp": "2017-07-20T06:35:09.196Z",
  "serviceUrl": "http://127.0.0.1:53484",
  "channelId": "emulator",
  "from": {
  "id": "ijfi3f969c6fij756",
  "name": "Bot"
},
"conversation": {
"id": "g671h707amhch9326"
},
"recipient": {
"id": "default-user"
},
"membersAdded": [],
"membersRemoved": [],
"text": "Hey there!",
"attachments": [],
"entities": [],
"replyToId": "efincfmnc40la0g7c",
"id": "hi959g2a8ji1fn86",
"localTimestamp": "2017-07-20T08:35:09+02:00"
}
```

We would like to add a few additional tags, to carry a bit more data about the message being sent.  For example, we might want to add a tag that shows we are expecting the user to reply with an email address.  Perhaps something like:

> {
>     "type": "message",
>    **"expecting": "email"**
>     "timestamp": "2017-07-20T06:35:09.196Z",
>     "serviceUrl": "http://127.0.0.1:53484", 
>     "channelId": "emulator",
>     "from": {
>     "id": "ijfi3f969c6fij756",
>      "name": "Bot" 
>   },

The idea is, that we'd like to use our custom tags to run additional code. Something we might want to do, for example, is:

```
if(reply.Expecting.Equals("email")
{
  //Do something awesome here.
}
```

**But, we haven't been able to find any information on how to customize these JSON messages.  Is it possible?  And if so, how would we go about it?**

Comment: You should have a look to the PromptDialog if you are trying to get user input

Comment: In Amio.io, we use `metadata` for that task. (I'm from Amio.io. Sorry, I couldn't resist to share how we're handling it. ;-) https://docs.amio.io/v1.0/reference#facebook-messenger-messages-metadata

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this with middleware. Here's the [C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-middleware) docs, and the [NodeJS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-intercept-messages) docs.

Basically, you set up your middleware off of the bot object:

```
bot.use({
    botbuilder: (sess, next) => {
        inbound(sess, next);
    }
    ,send: (evt, next) => {
        outbound(evt, next);
    }
});
```

...where `botbuilder` captures what the user sends and `send` captures what the bot sends.

Then you can define functions to deal with the messages, and alter them if you find that to be appropriate:

```
function inbound(sess: builder.Session, next: Function): void {
     console.log(sess.message);
    next();
}

function outbound(evt: builder.IEvent, next: Function): void {
    console.log(evt);
    next();
}
```

My recommendation is to *not* alter the message data structure itself, but to instead do your custom behaviors using the middleware, since altering these messages could have side effects. You can easily capture what you need to in the middleware, and then pass arguments to the `next()` function to allow the subsequent dialog to handle expectations.

Also, if all you're doing is trying to capture expected user input, regular expression matches with intent dialogs or trigger actions works quite well.

Comment: I'm not sure that using a middleware will be compliant with their use case, as it will require many code to check what is the message if they don't want to use the same addition for all messages

Comment: @Nicholas R Depends on what they are attempting to do. If all they're doing is looking for specific things like email addresses, then you're right, which is why I mentioned in the last paragraph that they can use intent dialogs or trigger actions with regular expression matching. But if they truly want to alter a message (not recommended) or perform some sort of middleware behavior or object passing, then they can do it with middleware.

Comment: yes you are right if that's for altering global things, but I was adding the comment to point out to the OP that it will not be easy for his example

Comment: @Nicholas R In the OP's case, I would just use a trigger action with a regex match on email addresses, if the email could come at any time (and was not something that was prompted for). If he is prompting for an email, then, as per your comment, that's just a text prompt. Since he asked to alter the message, however, I gave the middleware example first, but mentioned how he could pass the result to the next function rather than alter the message.

Comment: Yep. That's why I only commented: too broad to make a clear answer

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that  you are using .net Framework.

below is one option i can think of.
Introducing custom  properties to the Activity

Implement Activity class  on your **CustomActivity** class

```
 public class CustomActivity : Activity
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "cutomprop")]
        public string MyCustomProp { get; set; } = "Custom Prop";
    }
```

Then while posting back replies  consider creating Activity of type CustomActivity and do copy all props of original Activity to it (use tool Automapper for this purpose)

```
private async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
    {
        var activity = await result as Activity;

        ConnectorClient client = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(activity.ServiceUrl));

      var reply = new CustomActivity
        {

            ChannelData = activity.ChannelData,
            ChannelId = activity.ChannelId,
            ServiceUrl = activity.ServiceUrl,
            Name = activity.Name,
            Action = activity.Action,
            Type = activity.Type,
            Conversation = activity.Conversation,
            Code = activity.Code,
            From = activity.From,
            Value = activity.Value,
            Text = activity.Text,
            InputHint = activity.InputHint,
            Attachments = activity.Attachments,
            Entities = activity.Entities,
            ReplyToId = activity.ReplyToId,
            AttachmentLayout = activity.AttachmentLayout,
            HistoryDisclosed = activity.HistoryDisclosed,
            Id = activity.Id,
            LocalTimestamp = activity.LocalTimestamp,
            Locale = activity.Locale,
            MembersAdded = activity.MembersAdded,
            MembersRemoved = activity.MembersRemoved,
            Properties = activity.Properties,
            Recipient = activity.Recipient,
            RelatesTo = activity.RelatesTo,
            Speak = activity.Speak,
            SuggestedActions = activity.SuggestedActions,
            Summary = activity.Summary,
            TextFormat = activity.TextFormat,
            Timestamp = activity.Timestamp,
            TopicName = activity.TopicName

        };

        reply.Text = "I have colors in mind, but need your help to choose the best one.";
        reply.Type = ActivityTypes.Message;
        reply.TextFormat = TextFormatTypes.Plain;
       //set any other prop you want as per your needs
        await client.Conversations.SendToConversationAsync(reply);
        context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
    }
```

Below is the output i got

```
{
  "cutomprop": "Custom Prop",
  "type": "message",
  "id": null,
  "timestamp": "2017-07-20T12:44:41.504Z",
  "localTimestamp": "2017-07-20T18:14:41+05:30",
  "serviceUrl": "http://127.0.0.1:56931",
  "channelId": "emulator",
  "from": {
    "id": "default-user",
    "name": "default-user"
  },
  "conversation": {
    "id": "h0j9hn8bicfm8e509"
  },
  "recipient": {
    "id": "mcfimjke5aebemhf",
    "name": "Bot"
  },
  "textFormat": "plain",
```

Hope that helps... consider validating it for your scenario and look out for any other side effects . **not tested it on all channels, it works on emulator

Comment: In your case ok you add info in the message sent by the bot, but you will not get the property back on the next reply, will you? The channel will not copy/paste this block when replying. Here the OP ask for a property that he is able to check when getting a reply

Comment: @Nicolas you are right.. i misunderstood the context. thought its Bot ==> user communication.